# Is it safe to disconnect the condensate pipe from boiler

Tags: heating, boiler

I, like half of the UK right now, have got a problem with my boiler, and like the majority of those people, I understand it to be a problem with a frozen/blocked condensate pipe.

I've tried doing what I can to heat up the outside pipe, tried refilling the pressure, I've tried as many things as a layperson is likely to, and the occasion that I have been able to get hold of a plumber, they're inundated with calls, the only people I've got in touch with gave me conflicting suggestions, one guy said all I had to do was disconnect the condensate pipe from the boiler, let the excess water out, but that would let it heat up again, the other guy told me to absolutely not do that

I know this isn't the absolute use for SO, I'm just trying to fix my damn heating

Boiler is a Worcester Greenstar 25i, error code is 227 which says it cannot ignite the flame

[image: been told to disconnect this]

Comment: Frozen condensate is one possible cause for that error.   If there is a place near the  boiler where you can disconnect it, and pour some water down it you could confirm or rule it out.  If the water comes out the outside end of the pipe, it's not frozen.   If it backs up out your end, it's blocked and you have to look for other reasons.

Comment: "Let the excess water run out" is a terrible idea.   If you disconnect the pipe it should only be to help you confirm or rule out the pipe as the problem, not to try to bypass it.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I wanted to know, I'm not aiming to fix this myself, but you can't get hold of a plumber at this point until some point next week, there isn't a lot of options aside from wait and hope, and to paraphrase themselves, this is all they'd be doing if they came round, that's literally what one of them said, but I just wanted another opinion because I don't want to make it worse

Comment: If it is frozen you could look for ways to prevent that.   Reroute the pipe so it's more inside and less outside or wrap the outside part in foam pipe insulation, or if that's not enough, in electrically heated tape.

Comment: It's currently routed through the loft of the garage, and only about 2 feet of it is exposed outside, but I'm not sure what part of it has frozen

Comment: "error code is 227 which says it cannot ignite the flame" - frozen condensate may just be a symptom of it not firing every half an hour, which would probably keep it clear. (This is btw, *exactly* what we do here.) I've never worked on one of these, <strike> but if you feel confident, take the cover off and watch it try to ignite. Then tell us the sequence of what's happening and what you're hearing. E.g., a thing glows red, gas lights, then goes out. </strike>

Comment: https://youtu.be/JI-I24UiGFQ?t=479 - never mind. You're going to have to call someone I think. I can't tell heads from tails in there. ... Does your stove work? (verify gas to the house)

Comment: You could cut it and feed it into a bucket, but there might be flue gasses coming out of it. Have what you need to put it back together first before you do anything. Because, *oh sweet, now it works, let's go to bed* is no bueno.

Answer (score 1):

Failure to ignite can be caused by a blocked condensate pipe.

If you are going to disconnect the pipe, you need to work out where the water is going to go, as you can expect some water to pour out from the boiler.  The water is slightly acidic, but not terribly dangerous.

As for safety, there's something electrical directly below that pipe.  So think carefully how you are going to do it.